# Как определить логику при которой нажимая на layout/button показывать view и прятать ее при нажатии в другом месте экрана?

Tags: android, view, hide

При нажатии на layout должен показываться некоторая view, а когда я нажимаю в любом другом месте эта view должна исчезать. Я в функции dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) пишу логику которая за это отвечает, можно ли это сделать другим способом, есть ли другие варианты? Буду благодарна за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать реализовать 2-мя путями:

1. Создать корневой RelativeLayout куда поместить пустой вид и ваш основной вид с кнопкой(любые другие элементы). Пустой вид сделать match_parent и по клику на него - сделать, чтобы ваш основной вид исчезал.
2. Повесить на вью View.setOnFocusChangeListener(). В случае если фокус теряется с нужного вам вида, прописать логику по скрытию этого вью. Нужно добавить атрибут в разметку(включая родительские элементы тоже, если они имеются)

> android:focusableintouchmod=true

Comment: Спасибо, первый вариант я использую, а второй тоже думала, но фокус не теряеться при нажатии на другую обычную `view`, здесь нужно самому управлять фокусом, если я не права поправте меня.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял получается, что на втором вью тоже нужен setOnFocusChangeListener(), чтобы "схватить" новый фокус. Например, я использую editText с фокусом, при нажатии на кнопку фокус переходит на кнопку, теряется с editText'a.

Comment: Да, а если у Вас просто `view`, то Вам нужно в `onTouch()` вызвать `requestFocus()`.